# Changing variable's value of fragment from the activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, button, android-activity

I have an activity like this:

[image]

There are 2 buttons A and B on toolbar and a frame for fragment to take over. Say I have a string variable named `button_type` in fragment.

I want to have a system so that when I click button A in activity, the button_type in fragment sets to **A** and when I click button B in activity, the button_type in fragment sets to **B**.
How to do this?

Please note that I may click the buttons (A,B) when the fragment is already active (its not like after I click one button, the fragment comes.)

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Currently I am trying this:

In MainActivity I get similar string `button_type` and set it as **A** or **B** according as button click and use the method:

```
public String getData(){return button_type;}
```

And in fragment I use: `button_type= activity.getData();` in onViewCreated.

But it only seems to have the initial set value of **A** and **B** (which is **A**) and does not change when another button is clicked.

Comment: You have instance of your fragments. So make public method for set data in both fragments and use that method using instance of particular fragment.

Comment: Please elaborate. I tried using public methods but it is not working. So I need a detailed explanation to find where I am doing wrong.

Comment: Show method how did you make it?

Comment: Please check the edited question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best way if you use an `interface` for managing text in the fragment. the fragment will implement the interface. When the button click call the function in the fragment which is implemented by fragment.

Another way you can create an object of the fragment using `findFragmentByTag()` or `findFragmentById()` and then call the function in the fragment which handles the text.

Comment: I get it. A like from me!

Answer (score 1):

Create an `interface` with methods `onClickA(String buttonType)` and `onClickB(String buttonType)`.
Then create an object that implements this interface (or make fragment implement this interface by itself). I'll call this object listener.
call `setButtonType(String buttonType)` in listener methods implementation.
Then pass your listener to activity (you can get an instance of parent activity in fragment with `getActivity()` and cast it to your activity class) and in onClickListener of button A (in activity) call `listener.onClickA(yourString)` and do the same thing for button B.

Comment: small tip instead of `getActivity()` you can use `requireActivity()` also only one method can handle both click by checking param's value.